How to pass an object to a WPF user control
All I am trying to do is get an object (in this case an instance of "Addon") passed into a UserControl (in this case an "AddonControl") and have access to it as a member of the UserControl.
This object will never change over the lifetime of the UserControl, I don't need anything fancy, I just need access to the object so I can display its properties.
I tried about 15 different ways of trying to reference the (STATIC) object that I want to have my control access, none of them worked. I tried a DependencyProperty, didn't do anything. I've been searching this site for the better part of an hour and all of the answers are ridiculously bloated nonsense that don't even apply.
I expect a simple, sensible method to bind a static object to an instance of a control so I have access to the public properties of that object, as is normal in all object-oriented programming.
Here's the code for the relevant files:
Addon.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Compression;
//Currently a shell class, will be filled later.
namespace Magian_Launcher.lib.data
{
    public class Addon
    {
        public static Addon example = new Addon("Example Addon", "This is an example addon for testing the UI", "test.example.com", "", "test.example.com");
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string DownloadURL { get; set; }
        public string InstallLocation { get; set; }
        public string RepoURL { get; set; }

        public Addon() { }
        public Addon(string name, string description, string downloadURL, string installLocation, string repoURL)
        {
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
            DownloadURL = downloadURL;
            InstallLocation = installLocation;
            RepoURL = repoURL;
        }

        public void Install()
        {

        }
        public void Uninstall() 
        { 
        
        }
        public void Update() 
        { 
        
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name}\n{Description}\n{DownloadURL}\n{InstallLocation}";
        }
    }
}

AddonControl.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Magian_Launcher.AddonControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Magian_Launcher"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Author}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

AddonControl.xaml.cs
using Magian_Launcher.lib.data;
using MahApps.Metro.ValueBoxes;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Magian_Launcher
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for AddonControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AddonControl : UserControl
    {
        public AddonControl(Addon content)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.content = content;
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
        public Addon content {  get; set; }
        public string Title { get { return content.Name; } }
        public string Description { get { return content.Description; } }
        public string Author { get { return content.Author; } }
        public string RepoURL { get { return content.RepoURL; } }
        public Boolean AddonEnabled { get; set; }
    }
}

The goal is to display the public static Addon example...; using an AddonControl in literally any other file. I don't see any reason this should be as impossible as it has been.

Have you checked a valid instance of Addon class is actually passed into the AddonControl's constructor?

@emoacht the object that I'm trying to pass is Addon.example, which is a valid object. I just can't for the life of me figure out how I give it to the AddonControl in my xaml. To be clear, this is my first time working in WPF so the flow of data isn't something I fully understand yet.

Could you show the code where you pass that object to the AddonControl? Is it the most important, right?

@emoacht I don't have it, because I can't figure out what it's supposed to be. That's kinda the crux of the question. What I've been trying so far is variants on <local:AddonControl content="{Addon.example}"/>

There is no such syntax. The way to pass an object inside your app depends on its structure.

@emoacht That's a seriously unhelpful answer. "Just think about it" only works if I actually understand what's going on. If I understood what was going on I wouldn't be here asking this question.

There are a lot of questions; who instantiates it; who holds it; who changes it; and so on. They are all up to your app's structure and what you must decide.

The general answer to "how to pass an object to a control" is: by means of its DataContext property.

The additional properties in the UserControl are redundant.
There should not be a constructor with parameter.
The control should not set its own DataContext.

This is all code you need:
public partial class AddonControl : UserControl
{
    public AddonControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

In XAML, you would assign an Addon instance like this:
<local:AddonControl>
    <local:AddonControl.DataContext>
        <local:Addon Name="Example Addon" .../>
    </local:AddonControl.DataContext>
</local:AddonControl>

The static example member of the Addon class could be used like this:
<local:AddonControl DataContext="{x:Static local:Addon.example}"/>


I believe that's simpler than you think. Just feed the DataContext with the instance of the Addon class. The XAML says the bindings are straight to the DataContext.
Furthermore, since you don't use any notification, better to move the InitializeComponent as last within the constructor.
public partial class AddonControl : UserControl
{
    public AddonControl(Addon content)
    {
        this.DataContext = content;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public Boolean AddonEnabled { get; set; }
}

I didn't try, but it should work.

I appreciate the answer and I'll keep this pattern in mind, however my issue is a level above. The problem I'm having is actually getting an Addon to the AddonControl in the first place.
